# When to invalidate session

Tags: http, session, cookies, session-cookies

This is a general question regarding web session management.
What is the best practice approach to managing session timeout?

Assume a system where a user logs in, a session is created on the server, and a token identifier is sent back to the client (via `httpOnly` cookie).

If the user attempts some access-based check where the session is validated, presumably it makes sense to update an expiry time on the session in the DB. Does this also mean that when this happens, we should update the expiry time on the session token cookie to match?

This seems like the most obvious solution to me, but constantly rewriting the cookie seems like a lot of overhead.

Any insight into best-practice approaches is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to manage session timeout to keep user logged-in, prevent he/she from accidental logout?**

To keep user logged-in, it is not necessary to constantly rewrite the cookie. All you need to do is making the session token cookie's expires as `Session`, then as long as browser is open (client keeps using your site), the session token cookie is valid. Server does not need to know the session expires time (as there is no pre-defined session expires time any more), not mention store it in DB. After user close the browser, the session token cookie is cleared, and session is terminated (invalidated).

Normally, there will be a "session timeout" setting in server, such as `session-timeout` in Struts2, which kills the session if client doesn’t make any request after some time.

**How to make session "validate" even if user closes the browser? That is, how to implement the "remember me for 1 week" feature?**

To implement this feature, a new token cookie is used (e.g. `RememberMeToken`). When user login successfully (possibly enable the "Remember me" checkbox on UI), server will generate a unique random token and store it in DB (together with its expires time for security reason), make it belong to user account. This `RememberMeToken` cookie's expires time is pretty long (1 week for example), and will be sent back to browser together with login response.

When user close the browser and re-visit the site later (or the user is inactive for long time and the session is killed in server side), server checks session token cookie and find it's missing/invalid. At this point, `RememberMeToken` will be checked and compared with token stored in DB, if there is a match, server will make auto-login operation for corresponding user, and return generated session token cookie to browser. This all happens in backend, client user won't feel anything.

After 1 week since user enable the "Remember me" checkbox on UI and login, the `RememberMeToken` cookie is expired, and user need to login again if he/she opens browser and visit the site.

Comment: If you don't store the session token id on the server (your first example), how can you check it's valid and not just one someone has made up?

Comment: The session token id itself is stored on server (in memory or in DB), but the expires time of session token id is not stored.

Comment: Will this not be an eternally valid session identifier? If - somehow - the token id is retrieved by some 3rd party, couldn't they use the id whenever they want? Even after the token cookie would have invalidated?

Comment: Good question! You can config some "session timeout" value in server, such as `session-timeout` setting in Struts2, which kill the session if client doesn’t make any request after some time. But this "timeout value" is different from "expires time" -- server doesn't need to know when (on which timestamp) the token will be expired.

Comment: p.s. The `RememberMeToken`'s expires time is pre-defined and should be stored in DB for security reason.